# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python

i'm newbie so i don't understand why am i getting error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'"?

````
img = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
print("Image Properties")
print("- Number of Pixels: " + str(img.size))
print("- Shape/Dimensions: " + str(img.shape))```
````

Comment: Basically, `imread` failed silently, so `img` is `None`

Comment: It means that img variable holds None or null value because the file might not be available in current directory

Comment: I would say, the `imread` fails and thus returns `None`

Comment: I guess the path "cat.jpg" is not correct, so `imread` can't find it and returns `None`. Check if the image lies in the same directory as from which you call the scripts.

Comment: check if the file `cat.jpg` exists

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give more details, and a minimal reproducible example with code you wrote yet / sample data / and full error messages
about your trial to solve this problem, so we can reproduce and help.
See MRE here: [MRE]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by lack of `cat.jpg` file, please `import os` and add

```
print(os.path.exists('cat.jpg'))
```

immediately before

```
img = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
```

If it outputs `False` this mean `cat.jpg` is not there. You might use `print(os.getcwd())` to check where `cat.jpg` should be placed xor provide full path to file to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error on line 3 because you are taking the `size` of `img`, and `img` is (according to the interpreter), `None`.

So why is it `None`? You want to look at its definition.

```py
img = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
```

So what happens is that imread returns `None`. When does that happen? When the file doesn’t exist.

Therefore, the file `cat.jpg` is not in the **working directory** of your python program.

Therefore you will want to check if your program was launched in the right directory (or use `os.chdir` to change the directory).

Answer (score 0):

The `img` has no attribute named `size`

Looks like the `cv2.imread('cat.jpg')` is returning unexpected value. Try printing `img` and then you can debug further. Maybe it can't find the cat.png file in the specified location.

Answer (score 0):

The object `img` is invalid so it can't have any properties (like size). So when you ask for the `size`, there's nothing associated with the `size` attribute.

The problem is either:

1. The file is corrupted in some shape or form
2. The path is incorrect (try to use absolute paths)
3. The file doesn't exist

*Relative path:* `\photos_folder\cat.jpg` 
**Absolute path:** `C:\users\donkey\Documents\project_1\photos_folder\cat.jpg`